# Bootstrap 5 columns per row on desktop, 3 on table, 2 on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make bootstrap 5 columns per row on desktop, 3 on table, 2 on mobile?

Here is my current code, not having any luck:

```
<div class="row row-cols-5">
    <div class="col col-xs-6">
        R1
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6">
        R2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6">
        R3
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6">
        R4
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6">
        R5
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="row row-cols-lg-5">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```
<div class="row row-cols-lg-5">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

For more about bootstrap grid, please see [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).